# Почему не выводится "Nickname"?

Tags: php

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$sdd_db_host='';//Имя хоста
$sdd_db_name='';//Название бд
$sdd_db_user='';//Пользователь
$sdd_db_pass='';//Пароль
@mysql_connect($sdd_db_host,$sdd_db_user,$sdd_db_pass);//Подключение
@mysql_select_db($sdd_db_name);//Выбор базы
mysql_query ("set_client='utf8'");//Следующие 4 строки решают проблему с 
кодировкой.
mysql_query ("set character_set_results='utf8'");
mysql_query ("set collation_connection='utf8_general_ci'");
mysql_query ("SET NAMES utf8");
$id = $_GET['id'];
$row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id= 
$id"));//Запрос

echo '
<div class="Block">
Steamid '.$_SESSION['steamid'].'
<br>Nickname '.$_SESSION['name'].'
</div>';
?>
```

Comment: А где сама установка `$_SESSION['name']`?

Comment: @Pyramidhead то есть,чтобы вывести name и др,я должен вписать:
$SESSION['  '] отдельно.Я вас правильно понял?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У тебя может что то и хранится в $_SESSION['name'], но ты не можешь это прочесть. Я так понимаю, что это отдельный файл. Тебе в этом файле нужно стартануть сессию. Т.е. session_start(). До попытки вывода глобального массива

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73479/discussion-on-answer-by------nickname).